# In python is there a function/module that replaces all variables in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, ini

I have the following challenge:
I have a set of template files that have different values across my DTAP environment.
I want to replace them using python.

In ANT i know there is a function like:

```
<target name="generate-env-plan">
  <replace file="${env.WORKSPACE}/properties/configplan-template.xml" replacefilterfile="${env.WORKSPACE}/properties/dev.properties"/>
</target>
```

Which replaces all variables in the configplan-template.xml (${property} style) with properties known in dev.properties.

So far I could not find anything. For now I seem to be stuck in writing my own function that does this for me. The function then should contain a double for loop (looping trough both the lines in the file and the properties in my ini file and then replacing them using a string function.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: @martijn_van_der_kamp, see https://chameleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ is this suitable for your use case?

Comment: looks interesting ill have a look!